# Search instruction in PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to search a value in a specific mysql database column via PHP. However, it's not working. I tried many different ways and I had no success so far.

I'm trying the following code:

```
<?php

        require('connect.php');

    $search= 'search';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `user1` WHERE `description` LIKE '%'a'%'";
    if($result){
         $smsg = $query;
    }else{
         $fmsg ="Sorry, nothing was found. Try using our menu on top left.";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Not working means you get an error or zero results?

Answer (score 1):

Change it:

```
"SELECT * FROM `user1` WHERE `description` LIKE '%'a'%'";
```

to

```
"SELECT * FROM `user1` WHERE `description` LIKE '%a%'";
```

and try again. It will return you all the rows in which `description` column contains character `a`.